# Why is my Heroku app crashing when I push master.key live?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-ses, ruby-on-rails-6

Our app works fine on development.   We are setting up Amazon SES, and it works perfectly on local.

We use rails credentials, and have a master.key, a development.key, and a production.key.

But as soon as we push the master key live, the app crashes.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the the rails master key is  irrelevant if you are using keys on an environmental basis, i.e. development.key and production.key.

Therefore, when launching live on Heroku, you do *not* want to use the master.key.  You want to use the production.key.

This is what finally solved the heroku ses issue we were having.

How to properly set that production.key?

First: it is *still* called `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` on Heroku.

Second: you can either post the production.key to Heroku via the console:

```
heroku config:set RAILS_MASTER_KEY=`cat config/credentials/production.key`
```

Or you can set it manually on heroku in the 'settings' section by clicking on 'Environmental Variables'.

Comment: Umm, if you're setting it via an ENV var why even bother with the file? You shouldn't be checking your keys into git so how are you even uploading it?

Comment: We are not using ENV environmental variables.  It's just called that on Heroku.  The keys are not checked into git.  By using the above command, it grabs the production.key from your local, and pushes it live to heroku.

Comment: Ah yeah sorry. Missed the use of `cat` and variable expansion. Heroku's config vars are actually exposed as ENV vars to the stack. So yes, you are using an environmental variable. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars